# Poisson Distribution and Total propability theorem question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

The number of balls we get from our grandpa follows the poisson distribution with $\lambda =1/5$ ball/year.  The probability of getting a red ball from him is 0.08 .

Q: Calculate the probability of getting a red ball in the upcoming 5 years.

I know that i have to use the total probability theorem but i cant figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of balls obtained from grandpa and let $R$ be the number of red balls with $0 \le R \le N$. Clearly, if you know $N$, then $R \sim \mathcal{B}(N, p)$ where $p = 0.08$. So you can condition on $N$ to get
$$
\mathbb{P}[R = 0]
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[R = 0, N = n]
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[R = 0 | N = n] \mathbb{P}[N=n]
$$
and both factors are now easy to compute. Can you finish?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? The answer to my question according to my textbook is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-0.92^i) \mathbb{P}[N = i]$ . I dont know how the first part $(1-0.92^i)$ is produced, The binomial formula does not give this as an output .

Comment: I gave you an example, mine deals with $\mathbb{P}[R=0]$. You actually need $\mathbb{P}[R>0]$. Can you use my approach? $0.92^i$ will come from the Binomial formula (for $k=0$)

Comment: Yes now i got it. So the complete answer for others to see is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[R <= 1] \mathbb{P}[N = i] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty [1-\mathbb{P}[R = 0]] \mathbb{P}[N = i]  = \sum_{i=0}^\infty [1-\binom{i}{0}0.08^0 0.92^i] \mathbb{P}[N = i]  = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-0.92^i) \mathbb{P}[N = i]$ . Thank you for your help gt6989b

Comment: @ΧρηστοςΚαρυστινος yes, exactly :-)